# Geospatial Search has been turned down. StContainsFilter is no longer supported

Tags: google-app-engine, geospatial, permission-denied

Hi I am getting the following error on my geospatial query

Geospatial Search has been turned down. StContainsFilter is no longer supported.

I upgraded all my jars to the latest version and was able to generate the index on my geoPt column but I am getting this error. Everything works fine running locally. Any ideas?

code:

```
Query.Filter result = null;
GeoPt geo = new GeoPt(((GeoSearch) value).getLatitude(), ((GeoSearch) value).getLongitude());
            Query.GeoRegion.Circle circle = new Query.GeoRegion.Circle(geo, ((GeoSearch) value).getRadius());
            result = new Query.StContainsFilter(key, circle);
Query q = new Query(type.getName()).setFilter(compositeFilter);
PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an answer geospatial queries no longer work in google appengine datastore since Oct. 2018.  They have not updated the documentation or updated the local environment to reflect this.  Thanks google.